# Adding users to roles outside of controller using MVC template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the standard MVC template and can happily create users and add them to roles from my controller.

My question is can I do this from one of my Models?

To clarify I'd like to move the new user logic from my controller to my UserSetting class

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserSettingsViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          UserSetting userSetting = new UserSetting(model);
            UserSetting.Create(userSetting);
       }
       }
```

My UserSetting Class:

```
public class UserSetting : Controller 
{

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public static void Create(UserSetting userSetting)
    {
        switch (userSetting.AccountType)
        {
            // InternalUser
            case 0:

                AddOrUpdateInternalUser(userSetting);

                break;
            // ExternallUser
            case 1:
                AddOrUpdateExternalUser(userSetting);
                break;
            // InternaDoctor
        }

    }

    public async void AddOrUpdateInternalUser(UserSetting userSetting)
    { 

    var db = new V2Context();

    db.UserSettings.AddOrUpdate(userSetting);

      await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(userSetting.UserName, UserManager.GetRoles(userSetting.UserName).ToString());
      await  UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(userSetting.UserName, "newrole");

    db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how to relate a role to a model? Is this ASP.NET Identity or something else? More info needed.

Comment: Agreed. Your question is not clear. The controller is the actor. It can call something on one of your models, but the model alone can't do anything on its own. Not sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene I've updated my question

Comment: thanks @ChrisPratt I've update my question

Comment: Assuming you encapsulate that logic into a method, I don't see why it wouldn't work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TiesonT.

I've tried `        public async static void AddOrUpdateInternalUser(UserSetting userSetting)
        { 
        
        var db = new BeatBoxV2Context();

        db.UserSettings.AddOrUpdate(userSetting);

           await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(UserManager.GetRolesAsync(userSetting.UserName).ToString());
            UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userSetting.UserName, "newrole");

        db.SaveChanges();

        }`

This throws "cannot access static property in non static context"

Comment: Okay, for starters, edit that into your question, as comments aren't built to display large chunks of code. Then, why is that a static method, and where is it defined?

Comment: thanks @TiesonT. have updated my question to show the code that I currently have. There are no red lines however I cant debug right now.
At first glance does this look correct?

Comment: If UserSetting is a controller, the name (by convention) should be UserSettingController. It also looks like you're using the same name as an entity from your Entity Framework mapping; that's bound to cause problems. And I still don't get why that one method is static, as you haven't answered my previous question yet.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your code doesn't look too bad to me, at least in the sense of being concise. The controller is supposed to be responsible for things like working with the database, so I don't see a strong need for you to abstract any of that away. You might be able to turn like three lines of code into one by calling a method on a helper class, but does that really make any difference in the long run? No, and in fact, one could argue that you are actually *adding* complexity at that point, such that you now have to look in two places rather than one, just to move such a small amount of code out.

Also, if you were to move this code out to a helper class, then you would also need to inject your context into it. A lot of developers make the fatal mistake of trying to new up their context inside another class, and that will only cause problems.

Personally, I just try to keep my action methods light and create protected methods on the controller, which the actions utilize, to do the heavy lifting. It's the same practice Microsoft follows in their sample code for things like Identity. Long and short, keep the code in the controller unless there's an exceptionally good reason to move it out.

If your actions are getting too heavy, refactor the code out into private/protected methods (depending on whether you care about being able to subclass the controller or not) on the controller. Then, if you have code that is applicable to more than one controller, factor that out into some helper class that each can utilize.